# jquery dynamic form submission

Tags: jquery

Dynamically added select multiple drop down options using the perl cgi.  When I submit the form the select fields are not getting passed via post data.

Submit jquery handler

```
$("#srch_id_form").submit(function()
        {
         alert('Form is submitting');
        $(this).serialize();
         return true;
        });


});
```

Select multiple dropdown in the dynamic html

```
   <form id="srch_id_form" name="srch_form" method="post" action="testpost.cgi" >

      **                                        <!-- Selected drop down -->
             <select id="srch_id_opt_selchanges"  size="4" name="srch_n_selchanges">
             <option value="label" readonly="readonly"> *** Press Add Button to create the selection *** </option>
                                                </select>
        **
   </form>
```

Jquery for adding dynamically adding select options to the id "#srch_id_opt_selchanges" when a add button is clicked

```
$('#srch_addimg').click(function() {
    var str="";
    var selTxt="";
    var selVal="";
    var txtVal="";

    selTxt= $("#srch_chgdropdown option:selected").text();
    selVal=$("#srch_chgdropdown option:selected").val();
    console.log("test value:" +  $("#srch_chgdropdown option:selected").text() +"---");
    txtVal=$("#srch_filltxt").val();

    if(!txtVal) {
        alert('Please fill the Value for ' + selTxt);
    }
    else {
        subVal=selTxt+"="+txtVal;
       $("#srch_id_opt_selchanges").append("<option value='" + subVal+"'>" +subVal+ "</option>");
    }

 });
```

Comment: jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need set  default value before submit:

```
  $("#srch_id_opt_selchanges").append("<option selected='selected' value='" + subVal+"'>" +subVal+ "</option>");
```